# React - List icons with different param

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use the map function but I can't get it right.
I have a side-bar which I want to show some icons. Here is an example without the map.

```
    const SideBar = () => {

    return (
        <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 h-screen w-20 m-0 flex flex-col bg-gray-100 text-white shadow-lg">
            <SideBarIcon icon={<FaFire size="30" />} />
            <SideBarIcon icon={<FaPoo size="30" />} />
        </div>
    );
};

const SideBarIcon = ({ icon, text = "tooltip "}) => (
    <div className="sidebar-icon group">
        {icon}
        <span class="sidebar-tooltip group-hover:scale-100">{text}</span>
    </div>
);
```

Here is an example with the map function

```
const SideBar = () => {
    const icons = [FaFire, FaPoo];

    return (
        <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 h-screen w-20 m-0 flex flex-col bg-gray-100 text-white shadow-lg">
            {icons.map(function(icon) {
                return <SideBarIcon icon={<icon size="30"/>}/>
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

const SideBarIcon = ({ icon, text = "tooltip "}) => (
    <div className="sidebar-icon group">
        {icon}
        <span class="sidebar-tooltip group-hover:scale-100">{text}</span>
    </div>
);
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply putting `icon` inside the tags, it thinks you're rendering an HTML element called icon, therefore it's not rendering the mapped item. It also wouldn't work if you set it as `<{icon}/>`, because it would be trying to render an empty element.

Luckily, there's an easy fix -- Just capitalize Icon, and React will render it as a JSX Component.

```
{icons.map(function(Icon) {
    return <SideBarIcon icon={<Icon size="30"/>}/>
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
{icons.map(function (Icon) {
    return <SideBarIcon icon={<Icon size="30"/>}/>
})}
```

Components start with capital letters, just change `icon` to `Icon`.
Please do not forget to use key prop for your mapped items.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 0):

```
const SideBar = () => {
const icons = [<FaFire size="30" />, <FaPoo size="30" />];

return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 h-screen w-20 m-0 flex flex-col bg-gray-100 text-white shadow-lg">
        {icons.map(function(icon) {
            return <SideBarIcon icon={icon}/>
        })}
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using `icon` in lowercase, it is not recognized as a `jsx` component. To fix this, change it to uppercase.

turn this

```
        {icons.map(function(icon) {
            return <SideBarIcon icon={<icon size="30"/>}/>
        })}
```

to this

```
        {icons.map(function(Icon) {
            return <SideBarIcon icon={<Icon size="30"/>}/>
        })}
```

Also, if the underlying components allow it, you could use the direct invocation, like so:

```
        return <SideBarIcon icon={icon({size:"30"})/>
```

Keep in mind, that in most cases that is not what you want, and it might introduce hard-to-fix bugs.

Comment: Do not do this. Components should never be invoked directly, they're not plain functions.

Comment: @Json Miller I don't see why you should `never` invoke components directly. In some cases that won't fit, but there are some use cases where you have to do it, and there is nothing wrong about it. Or do you have a link to the react documentation, which forbids that?

Comment: My comment was based on my knowledge from 6 years of maintaining Preact. A few reasons to avoid invoking components directly: class components will simply throw (cannot invoke a class as a function), function components that use hooks will have their hook data slots incorrectly merged into the caller component, function components don't just take props as their argument (the second argument is context), direct calls do not properly interoperate with forwardRef. Also, keep in mind: there are real performance disadvantages to invoking components directly - you're bypassing diff optimizations.

Comment: I should add: you can totally invoke functions from within a component or render method - just don't think about it as "invoking a component". It's a plain function, not a component. Components have backing data structures in the renderer, can self-update, store data, access context, etc.